# SQLite.Net PCL for windowsPhone 8.1

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

Im creating a universal app trying to use `SQLite.Net PCL`. As it seems there is still no nuget-package available for `WP81`. From what I can understand there are workarounds that might work and I would like to hear from one of you if you suceeded.

There seem to be lots of people wondering the samw question but not much help out there.

```
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/680eb2ab-206d-420e-88b7-05f2b99978b4/sqlitenet-pcl-on-windows-phone-81-platform?forum=wpdevelop

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586902/sqlite-net-pcl-support-workaround-for-windows-phone-8-1
```

Hope someone herre has a solution to share. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is still a problem for you?
I followed following steps and got SQLite-net up and running in an universal app scenario ( so win 8.1 and win phone 8.1 ).

http://depblog.weblogs.us/2015/01/06/sqlite-net-and-sqlite-net-extensions-with-universal-apps/

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735234/1851264 . It works on windows phone 8.1 (store app).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunatley this one does not seem to deal witch the PCL-version.